# Manipulate request data using backpack 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'd like to change a data before saving I have a date where I don't need seconds only minutes, and I want the seconds to be 00 all the time. I tried Laravel's `prepareForValidation()` method in my request class, but it turned out it does not affect value stored in database. I also tried backpack's `modifyField()` but I couldn't find a way to modify value before store or update.

What's the best way to perform this? Using Laravel7 and Backpack 4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's a specific backpack way of doing it, but you can use a mutator on your model to modify the value before it gets saved to the database.

In your case, if your fieldname is "date_time" you could do something like:

```
class MyModel extends Model {

  setDateTimeAttribute ($value) {

    $value = Carbon::parse($value)->second(0);

    $this->attributes['date_time'] = $value;  
  }
}
```

This has the benefit that the mutation will occur every time your date_time attribute is updated - whether you update it through your Backpack Crud or from some other method.

**References**:

- Laravel Mutators:  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator
- Modifying Dates with Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-settersfluent

Comment: There is no Backpack-specific way to do this. Since it's something that has to do with how Models store information, this is how I would do it too - using a Laravel Mutator. Btw excellent answer, Dave.